# What does the padlock icon in Pokemon summary page mean?

Tags: pokemon-scarlet-violet

I've noticed that there's a padlock icon in every Pokemon summary page, but I can't figure out its meaning or how to use it.

[image]

How can you lock a Pokemon? And lock from what?
Or is that an unused feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon will automatically light up when the game locks the Pokémon for various reasons. Two examples that I have seen are if the Pokémon is in a battle team that's registered for a tournament, or if it's currently being offered for a surprise trade.

When it's locked, you can't modify it, move it to your party, or use it.

For instance, this Rockruff is currently being offered for a surprise trade:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no proven answer as to what the padlock means at the moment. Some theorize that it is an unused asset accidentally left in (or something that may be used in a DLC) or that the symbol will light up if the Pokémon in question cannot be traded or released. As of writing this, there is no clear answer.

Comment: I just checked, and the lock does *not* light up when you change your bike into battle mode, so if it's intended to indicate when a Pokemon can't be traded or released, it's not doing a very good job.